# Sending mail to smtp server requiring authentication using Dev C++

Tags: c++, email

I am working on a program that connects to a tcp server, get some data and under certain conditions need to send an alert via email.(I'm helping someone with a school project)
I'm using DevC++.

It's been a few years since I've had anything to do with programming and have never done any programming in a network environment. (Hope that make sense)

I got the TCP client and log file part going, but I can't get the mail sending part to work.

Since I'm relatively inexperienced I've already wasted a lot of time, for example first of all I thought of trying POCO, but now it looks like you need Visual C++ to build the libraries.
Next I tried jwsmtp, but the examples I could find didn't do authentication, and it seems that authentication is a must nowadays. Next I tried libCurl, but can't get the examples to work, first of all I get CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM was not declared in this scope, I read in some post that is caused by error in newest version, then the curl header files started giving all sorts of errors.

My problem is that I am now fast running out of time. I would love to get it all working by myself, and even learn enough to write my own code, not just modifying and pasting together examples, but I made a promise and the deadline doesn't give me that option.

Can someone please help with anything that will actually work on windows using DevC++ sending mail to a gmail account?

Comment: Did you try this one? - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28806/SMTP-Client

Comment: What you need to do is get OpenSSL and link to it and just construct the mail headers and send it through a socket.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will be using Mingw and MSYS.. What I did was download the latest OpenSSL from: http://www.openssl.org/source/

Then I opened MSYS and ran the following commands:

`./configure mingw no-shared --prefix='C:/OpenSSL'`

It should print `Configured for mingw` if successful.

Next I went to the OpenSSL source and then the test folder. I opened `md2test.c` and replaced `dummytest.c` with: `#include "dummytest.c"`. I did the same thing for `rc5test.c` and for `jpaketest.c`.

Next I ran the following commands:

`make depend && make install`

This will build the static libraries. If you want to build the shared libraries then you need to replace `no-shared` with `shared` in the first command (the `./configure` line).

When finished, I created some raw sockets and sent emails as follows (need to do some error checking within the `sendemail` function but I hope you get the gist of it.. It works):

```
/**  © 2014, Brandon T. All Rights Reserved.
  *
  *  This file is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
  *  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
  *  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
  *  (at your option) any later version.
  *
  *  This file is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  *  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  *  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  *  GNU General Public License for more details.
  *
  *  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  *  along with this file.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
  */

#if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#ifndef __cplusplus
typedef enum {false, true} bool;
#endif

bool ssl_init_count = 0;

typedef struct
{
    int sock;
    const char* address;
    unsigned short port;
} sock_info;

typedef struct
{
    SSL* ssl;
    SSL_CTX* ctx;
} ssl_info;

typedef struct
{
    char b64username[256];
    char b64password[256];
} email;

bool initsocket()
{
    #if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
    WSADATA wsaData = {0};
    return !WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    #else
    return true;
    #endif
}

void destroysocket(sock_info* info)
{
    #if defined _WIN32 || defined _WIN64
    shutdown(info->sock, SD_BOTH);
    closesocket(info->sock);
    WSACleanup();
    #else
    shutdown(info->sock, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(info->sock);
    #endif
}

bool connectsocket(sock_info* info)
{
    struct sockaddr_in* sockaddr_ipv4 = NULL;
    struct addrinfo* it = NULL, *result = NULL;
    getaddrinfo(info->address, NULL, NULL, &result);

    for (it = result; it != NULL; it = it->ai_next)
    {
        sockaddr_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in*)it->ai_addr;
        info->address = inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr);

        if (strncmp(info->address, "0.0.0.0", 7))
            break;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if ((info->sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error creating socket..");
        return false;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
    memset(&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(info->port);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(info->address);

    if (connect(info->sock, (struct sockaddr*)&SockAddr, sizeof(SockAddr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error connecting socket..");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool setssl(sock_info* sockinfo, ssl_info* sslinfo)
{
    sslinfo->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    if (sslinfo->ctx)
    {
        sslinfo->ssl = SSL_new(sslinfo->ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(sslinfo->ssl, sockinfo->sock);
        return SSL_connect(sslinfo->ssl) != -1;
    }
    return false;
}

void removessl(sock_info* sockinfo, ssl_info* sslinfo)
{
    if (sslinfo->ctx)
    {
        SSL_CTX_free(sslinfo->ctx);
    }

    if (sslinfo->ssl)
    {
        SSL_shutdown(sslinfo->ssl);
        SSL_free(sslinfo->ssl);
    }

    sslinfo->ssl = NULL;
    sslinfo->ctx = NULL;
}

void initssl()
{
    if (!ssl_init_count)
    {
        SSL_library_init();
        SSL_load_error_strings();
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    }

    ++ssl_init_count;
}

void freessl()
{
    if (!--ssl_init_count)
    {
        ERR_free_strings();
        EVP_cleanup();
        CRYPTO_cleanup_all_ex_data();
    }
}

void sslb64encode(const char* buffer, char* outbuffer)
{
    char* b64str = NULL;
    BIO* b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO* mem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    b64 = BIO_push(b64, mem);
    BIO_write(b64, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    BIO_flush(b64);

    int len = BIO_get_mem_data(mem, &b64str);
    memcpy(outbuffer, b64str, len);
    outbuffer[len] = '\0';
    BIO_free_all(b64);
}

void initemail(const char* username, const char* password, email* outemail)
{
    char ubuffer[256];
    char pbuffer[256];
    unsigned int bytes_written = 0;

    sslb64encode(username, &ubuffer[0]);
    sslb64encode(password, &pbuffer[0]);

    sprintf(outemail->b64username, "%s", ubuffer);
    sprintf(outemail->b64password, "%s", pbuffer);
}

bool printsocketbuffer(ssl_info* sslinfo)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    unsigned int bytes_read = SSL_read(sslinfo->ssl, &buffer[0], sizeof(buffer));
    if (bytes_read > 0)
    {
        printf("%.*s", bytes_read, buffer);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void sendemail(ssl_info* sslinfo, const char* username, const char* password, const char* recipient, const char* from, const char* to, const char* message, const char* subject, unsigned int messagelen)
{
    email em;
    char buffer[512];
    unsigned int bufflen = sizeof(buffer);
    initemail(username, password, &em);

    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, "HELO\r\n", 6);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n", 12);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    bufflen = sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\n", em.b64username);
    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, buffer, bufflen);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    bufflen = sprintf(buffer, "%s\r\n", em.b64password);
    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, buffer, bufflen);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    bufflen = sprintf(buffer, "MAIL FROM: <%s>\r\n", username);
    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, buffer, bufflen);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    bufflen = sprintf(buffer, "RCPT TO: <%s>\r\n", recipient);
    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, buffer, bufflen);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, "DATA\r\n", 6);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    bufflen = sprintf(buffer, "From: <%s><%s>\r\n", from, username);
    bufflen += sprintf(&buffer[bufflen], "To: <%s><%s>\r\n", to, recipient);
    bufflen += sprintf(&buffer[bufflen], "Subject: <%s>\r\n", subject);
    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, buffer, bufflen);

    bufflen = 0;
    while (bufflen < messagelen)
    {
        bufflen += SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, &message[bufflen], messagelen - bufflen);
    }

    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, "\r\n.\r\n", 5);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);

    SSL_write(sslinfo->ssl, "QUIT\r\n", 6);
    printsocketbuffer(sslinfo);
}

int main()
{
    ssl_info sslinfo = {0};
    sock_info sockinfo = {0, "smtp.gmail.com", 465};

    const char* username = "ICantChooseUsernames@gmail.com";
    const char* password = "*****";
    const char* recipient = "ICantChooseUsernames@gmail.com";
    const char* message = "hello there!";
    const char* subject = "Testing Emails";
    const char* from = "Brandon";
    const char* to = "Brandon";
    unsigned int messagelen = strlen(message);


    if (initsocket())
    {
        if (connectsocket(&sockinfo))
        {
            initssl();

            if (setssl(&sockinfo, &sslinfo))
            {
                sendemail(&sslinfo, username, password, recipient, from, to, message, subject, messagelen);
            }
            else
            {
                ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
            }

            removessl(&sockinfo, &sslinfo);
            freessl();
        }

        destroysocket(&sockinfo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not wanting to sound stupid I've kept trying, but now I admit defeat before I really got anywhere. Running the ./configure command in MSYS just give "./configure: no such file or directory"

Comment: You need to do `cd "location of directory"`

Comment: Do you mean cd c:/msys ? I did, no joy unfortunately.

Comment: I mean `cd "C:/Users/MyUsername/OpenSSLDirectory"`

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I'm not going to get this working. Tried all openssl, mingw and msys directories. After speaking to a friend I got Visual Studio Express and got a c# example to work fairly quickly. Not having even seen c# before I couldn't rewrite everything else, so I just modified my example to make a mail sending application I call from my other program. Maybe not the best way but hey, it works and my time is up.
Hopefully I will be able to start learning this stuff. 
Thanks for trying to help this ignoramus, I really appreciate it.